# Cluster cluster_reports has an incorrect overload protection panic action: system-exit

Tags: python, oracle, server, weblogic12c

I run the WLST script and getting the below errors.

## Cluster Info

> Checking cluster type and overload actions: Feature usage measurement
> error:  Cluster cluster_reports has an incorrect overload protection
> panic action:  system-exit Feature usage measurement error:  Cluster
> cluster_forms has an incorrect overload protection panic action:
> system-exit WebLogic Server has features for detecting, avoiding, and
> recovering from overload conditions. WebLogic Server's overload
> protection features help prevent the negative consequences - degraded
> application performance and stability - that can result from
> continuing to accept requests when the system capacity is reached. In
> the license for WebLogic Server Basic, the configuration of any
> overload protection scheme at either a cluster or server level is not
> permitted. See the documentation:
> http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13701/overload.htm
> 2 error(s) detected

## Server Info

> Checking server mode and overload actions: Feature usage measurement
> error:  Server WLS_REPORTS has an incorrect overload protection panic
> action:  system-exit Feature usage measurement error:  Server
> WLS_FORMS has an incorrect overload protection panic action:
> system-exit Feature usage measurement error:  Server AdminServer has
> an incorrect overload protection panic action:  system-exit WebLogic
> Server has features for detecting, avoiding, and recovering from
> overload conditions. WebLogic Server's overload protection features
> help prevent the negative consequences - degraded application
> performance and stability - that can result from continuing to accept
> requests when the system capacity is reached. In the license for
> WebLogic Server Basic, the configuration of any overload protection
> scheme at either a cluster or server level is not permitted. See the
> documentation:
> http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13701/overload.htm
> 3 error(s) detected

Is there any way I can deactivate this option in WebLogic?

Comment: I currently have a WebLogic Basic License and needs to disable this overload protection feature to be license compliant.

Comment: Update panic action to 'Ignore take action' and select activate changes from the Admin Console. Note: Not all changes take effect immediately—some require a restart then run the python script again and it should not throw an error anymore.